# Stop div scroll when it reaches another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I got this answer here at SO to make a div scroll when the user scroll down the page. But, I need the div to stop when it reaches another div and stay in that position. How can I do that?

jQuery code:

```
(function($) {
    var element = $('.sim-area-sim'),
    originalY = element.offset().top;

    // Space between element and top of screen (when scrolling)
    var topMargin = 140;

    // Should probably be set in CSS; but here just for emphasis
    element.css('position', 'relative');

    $(window).on('scroll', function(event) {
        var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();

        element.stop(true, true).animate({
            top: scrollTop < originalY
                 ? 0
                 : scrollTop - originalY + topMargin
        }, 300);
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Thanks!

Comment: What means ` to make a div scroll when the user scroll down the page` ? Can you be more specific? HTML, CSS... anything?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan, it's a sticky div, that scrolls the div togheter with the page, just like fixed element. It works, but right now it's overlaping the content below, i need to stop when it reaches another div.

Comment: A div cannot scroll together with the page (in magical meanings). That's a DIV default behavior. A DIV can only be `fixed` to actually stick to the viewport - but than it doesn't scrolls.

Comment: Probably what you want to say is that you want that DIV fixed... but as soon another div reaches it's bottom edge, your DIV should start moving along ("un-fix itself").

Comment: This is what i have mate: https://jsfiddle.net/Lvwh3box/1/

Comment: See the third box on the sidebar, it follows when you scroll, this is what my code do right now, but after that third div, i have some content and i want it to stop when it reaches there

Comment: let me see a fiddle with "that botom content". (Also your DIV currently irritatingly jumps.. we'll fix that too.)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Lvwh3box/151/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***[jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Lvwh3box/153/)***

Here you go:

```
(function($) {
    var el = $('.follow-scroll'),
        next = el.next(),           // Who's the element's next element in HTML
        elOrgY = el.offset().top,
        elH = el.outerHeight(true),
        topMargin = 20;             // Space between element and top of screen (when scrolling)


    el.css('position', 'relative');

    $(window).on('scroll', function(event) {
        var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        var elNewTop = scrollTop - elOrgY + topMargin;
        var nextViewportY = next[0].getBoundingClientRect().top;
        var subtractToTop = Math.min( 0, nextViewportY - (elH+topMargin) ); // Return only 0 or negative numbers
        el.css({
            top: scrollTop < elOrgY - topMargin
                    ? 0
                    : elNewTop + subtractToTop
        }, 300);
    });
})(jQuery);
```

The `.animate()` was a really bad and ugly choice, use `.css()` instead to keep that element calmly fixed.
To explain the above, as you scroll, at some point, when the element reaches the window top edge you start to increase it's CSS `top` property to make it seem like it's fixed on screen - that means that you need to keep track of the `.next()` hitting element Y position respective the the window (viewport) top edge. To do that use JS's `getBoundingClientRect()` method and access the `.top` value of that next element.

**How to know when they collide?**

Well, first you need to calculate the height of your box right?  Than as you scroll do like you did with the element top position, but at some point you have to start subtracting to that value a negative value that's the result of the next element position colliding with your box.

```js
(function($) {
    var el = $('.follow-scroll'),
        next = el.next(),           // Who's the element's next element in HTML
        elOrgY = el.offset().top,
        elH = el.outerHeight(true),
        topMargin = 20;             // Space between element and top of screen (when scrolling)

   
    el.css('position', 'relative');
    
    $(window).on('scroll', function(event) {
        var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        var elNewTop = scrollTop - elOrgY + topMargin;
        var nextViewportY = next[0].getBoundingClientRect().top;
        var subtractToTop = Math.min( 0, nextViewportY-(elH+topMargin) ); // Return only 0 or negative numbers
        el.css({
            top: scrollTop < elOrgY - topMargin
                    ? 0
                    : elNewTop + subtractToTop
        }, 300);
    });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
/* http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/ */
html { box-sizing: border-box; }
*, *:before, *:after { box-sizing: inherit; }

/* https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/ */
.group:after { content: ""; display: table; clear: both; }

body { font: 15px/20px sans-serif; color: #444; }
p { margin-bottom: 30px; }

.wrapper { width: 100%; max-width: 700px; padding: 3%; }

.content, .sidebar { float: left; }

.content { width: 68%; margin-right: 5%; }

.sidebar { width: 27%; }

.box { background: #eee; border: 1px solid #ccc; padding: 10px; margin-bottom: 20px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper group">
    <div class="content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam euismod arcu ut diam maximus auctor. Sed malesuada maximus tellus, dignissim volutpat urna hendrerit at. Cras nisi turpis, mattis vitae ornare ut, bibendum et massa. Nulla at tellus a arcu luctus ultrices ac non felis. Maecenas euismod efficitur ipsum vel vestibulum. Nam imperdiet ipsum nunc, sit amet varius felis maximus quis. Etiam efficitur, mauris placerat luctus facilisis, ligula sem pellentesque nunc, ac viverra tellus velit sit amet purus. Proin a nunc id quam tempor blandit vitae id orci. Cras lectus turpis, varius nec elementum venenatis, suscipit ut nisl.</p>
        <p>Nulla condimentum est in leo mollis, sit amet varius erat pulvinar. Donec posuere turpis non est ultrices lobortis. Donec commodo aliquam sodales. Ut id finibus velit. Aenean tempus eget nulla at condimentum. Ut a arcu quis dui ultricies efficitur. Vestibulum suscipit diam ullamcorper velit tempor, in ullamcorper odio sollicitudin. Vestibulum congue nisl nibh, ut elementum quam tristique non. Nulla in sollicitudin dolor. Morbi ac justo nulla. Suspendisse massa neque, vestibulum id dolor non, congue rhoncus nibh.</p>
        <p>Phasellus porta tellus vel ipsum vehicula, nec fermentum lectus porta. Aenean viverra magna eu risus lacinia malesuada. Sed molestie auctor pharetra. Aliquam erat volutpat. Vestibulum in mi a orci tincidunt pellentesque. Sed et lectus eros. Nam imperdiet neque eu dolor gravida, interdum pellentesque justo rhoncus. Morbi tincidunt, ex nec pellentesque pulvinar, dui nulla tempor ipsum, sed consequat est tortor at neque. Suspendisse sed consequat urna. Nullam luctus, sem convallis volutpat mollis, sapien odio finibus elit, vitae fringilla enim leo sed velit. Vivamus fringilla ante laoreet blandit porta. Sed condimentum ut erat nec dignissim.</p>
        <p>Morbi ac scelerisque metus. Donec rhoncus diam urna, nec aliquet ex mollis ut. Sed a arcu ac risus semper pellentesque ut non nibh. Phasellus eu ullamcorper sem. Maecenas at tortor faucibus, consequat risus sed, egestas sapien. Suspendisse tortor lacus, congue sed velit vel, dictum sagittis eros. Proin eu nisl viverra, mattis velit vitae, tempor turpis. Ut sodales lacus in iaculis faucibus. Integer non metus non nulla malesuada rutrum ac non ipsum. Vivamus quam diam, suscipit sed velit vel, tincidunt imperdiet urna. Praesent dapibus augue a dignissim lacinia. Nullam pharetra volutpat ligula, quis aliquet mauris pharetra nec. Etiam finibus, neque in laoreet vehicula, lorem justo feugiat velit, ac accumsan neque lacus non tellus. Aliquam quis sagittis massa, a bibendum enim.</p>
        <p>Morbi vel elementum libero, vitae viverra est. Pellentesque sollicitudin neque at ligula suscipit, vel faucibus mauris consequat. Donec quis pharetra nulla, at tristique lacus. Nunc vel magna ultricies, hendrerit purus et, rhoncus dolor. Aliquam erat volutpat. Phasellus auctor malesuada augue, a iaculis sem mattis quis. Nulla facilisi.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar">
        <div class="box">
            First box
        </div>
        <div class="box">
            Second box
        </div>
        <div class="box follow-scroll">
            Third box (follows screen)
        </div>
        <div class="box" style="margin-top:200px;">
            Fourth box (thirt box needs to stop there)
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have used your code, and when i scroll down, the div disappears instead of going down, see it in my live website:  http://www.ngkntk.com.br/novosite/simulador-de-miscelanea/

Comment: @WilliamXavier have you done your research? Do you know what jQuery `.next()` does?

Comment: Well, not really, i'm kind of new at jquery, i'll have a look at it, sorry mate.

Comment: @WilliamXavier shoudl be obvious, in the fiddle demo you provided, the "sticky box" element next a NEXT element. the next element is the colliding next element sibling. In your website you don't have any .next() element.

Comment: @WilliamXavier to help you a bit: instead of using `el.next(),` use the desired element selector you need.

Comment: So, like in the fiddle, i have .box class, so when it reaches the .next('.box') element?

Comment: @William, in your website, `'.sim-area-sim'` does NOT have a `.next()` element to match! Use another selector.

Comment: Got it, i'll research a bit more to learn about .next(), BTW, your code worked with the desired element where i need it to stop, thanks a lot for your help mate. I'll really go learn about .next()